# How do I transfer files using Windows Remote Assistance?

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-access

I'm using [`Windows Remote Assistance`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Remote_Assistance) but I can't find how transfer files despite some tutorials on internet say it's possible. I didn't find any configuration for that and Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v/mouse right click copy doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidPostill I doubt there's a difference between 8 and 8.1 in remote assistance. To ask which windows version and distinguish between 8 and 8.1 in this context, suggests somewhat that there's a difference between 8 and 8.1 in this matter, and surely there isn't, so that's misleading

Comment: I'll find an alternative for transfer the files then. Thanks for the answer guys

Comment: @DavidPostill: You can post win 10 pro requirement to it work as answer too, I guess

Comment: @jack, comments cleaned up and moved to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I transfer files using Windows Remote Assistance?

> I can't find how to transfer files despite some tutorials on internet saying it's possible.
>
> I'm using Windows 10 Home edition on both machines.

Remote Assistance for Windows 7 and later doesn't support file transfer.

> In addition, Remote Assistance in Windows 7 has deprecated the file transfer feature that was available in Windows XP and Windows Vista. Compatibility with earlier versions is still supported, however-for example, if a file transfer is initiated from a Windows XP or Windows Vista computer, Windows 7 will accept the transfer.

Source [Improvements to Remote Assistance in Windows 7](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/improvements-remote-assistance-windows-7.html)

Note:

- Remote Assistance for Windows XP and Vista did support file transfer:

  > In the chat window, click Send a File.

  Source [To send a file by Remote Assistance](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ra_send_file.mspx?mfr=true)

---

#### Workarounds

- [Remote Desktop Connection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17463/windows-7-connect-to-another-computer-remote-desktop-connection) can do file transfer, but requires the target machine to be running Windows 10 Pro, so is not applicable for you.
- [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows/) can be used for remote support and also supports [file transfer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/424-how-can-i-send-large-files-with-teamviewer).
- Transfer the file(s) via some other service like [GoogleDrive](https://www.google.com/drive/), [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/), [ftp](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/free_ftp_client_for_windows) or [sftp](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/free_sftp_client_for_windows)
- Email can also be used if the file(s) are not too large.

Comment: you write "Remote Assistance for Windows 7 and later doesn't support file transfer.    I notice you've named every windows version there except for XP.  Is there a reason for that?

Comment: @barlop That is because (as I alluded to in earlier comments on the question)  Remote Assistance for Windows XP did support file transfer ("In the chat window, click Send a File." see [To send a file by Remote Assistance](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ra_send_file.mspx?mfr=true). Answer updated.

Comment: +1 well now that's a very comprehensive answer useful and informative to many

Comment: @barlop Thanks. I got there in the end with some prompting from you :)